# python library for Deep Reinforcement Learning

Tags: python, monte-carlo, reinforcement-learning

I have recently studied about deep RL algorithms like PPO,A3C . I want to train an RL agent using these algorithms. However I am finding it difficult to implement. So I am planning to use a library which will help me in the implementation. Can someone help me by suggesting an RL library that I can use to train an agent using PPO/A3C. I have googled a lot but couldn't find resources comparing/compiling any available frameworks.

Thanks

Comment: openai gym ....